# How read data from a JSON arry object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

I am trying to get a value from a JSON array in Javascript :

**The JSON array looks like :**

```
[
   {
      "_id": 0,
      "_entityMetadataList": [
         {
            "_metadataValue": "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails/1524101696032.jpg",
         },
         {
            "_metadataValue": "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails/1524101694488.jpg",
         }
      ],
      "_timeCreated": "Tue Jan 15 06:10:04 2019\n",
      "_timeUpdated": "Tue Jan 15 06:10:04 2019\n",
      "objectEntity": {
         "_id": 0,
         "_EntitySiteGUID": -1
      }
   }
]
```

How I go about it :

```
app.post('/sound', function (req, res) {
    let entitiesArray = req.body['filter'];

    console.log('entitiesArray: ' + JSON.stringify(entitiesArray._entityMetadataList[0]._metadataValue))
```

*(this is in a Node environment, by the way)*

I, however keep getting the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems you also need to pass the index for `revEntitiesArray`.

Try this

```
console.log('revEntitiesArray: ' + 
JSON.stringify(revEntitiesArray[0]._revEntityMetadataList[0]._metadataValue))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code can help

```
data = [
   {
      "_id": 0,
      "_revEntityMetadataList": [
         {
            "_metadataValue": "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails/1524101696032.jpg",
         },
         {
            "_metadataValue": "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/.thumbnails/1524101694488.jpg",
         }
      ],
      "_timeCreated": "Tue Jan 15 06:10:04 2019\n",
      "_timeUpdated": "Tue Jan 15 06:10:04 2019\n",
      "revObjectEntity": {
         "_id": 0,
         "_revEntitySiteGUID": -1
      }
   }
]`

data[0]["_revEntityMetadataList"][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed that the outermost reference is an array

```
revEntitiesArray[0]._revEntityMetadataList[0]._metadataValue
```

When in doubt, assign each part of your path expression to a local variable and step through with a debugger.